# Adding 12V power supply to existing Solar MPPT load circuit

Tags: power-supply, 12v, solar-charge-controller, mppt, lifepo4

I have a camper which has a small 12v power system consisting of a 50w solar panel, a generic 20ah LiFeP04 battery, an a 15A Victron MPPT controller whose 12v load output feeds directly to a fuse block that continues on to power lights, heater, USB, etc, etc

Its winter and the sun isn't shining much so Im scheming on adding some supplemental mains power.

I have a generic 120vAC/4A DC "lithium" battery charger I could hook directly to the battery and "pass-through" charge/feed the load as needed, but Im under the impression this "isnt good" for the battery. Although I cant find any info on this online.

Another idea would be adding a 120vAC/12V 15A power supply (marketed as a "waterproof LED power supply") to the fuse block terminals. 15A would give plenty of headroom for my needs.

Could this somehow damage the charge controller or battery? Should the two supplies be isolated with a switch or something? Perhaps a diode?

Is there a switch or simple circuit that would automatically "prefer" the AC power supply if it's available and fallback to the battery otherwise?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a relay triggered by the presence of the AC supply.